# Powering CO2 sensor with Battery

Tags: power, batteries, usb, raspberry-pi

I have a K-30 CO2 sensor connected to a Raspberry Pi 3 model B. When I connect the sensor to the Pi via serial and power the sensor with the Pi, my program works fine: the CO2 concentrations are displayed on the screen.

On the other hand, when I try to power the sensor with a portable battery, the program does not work: the Pi recognizes that the sensor is connected, but it doesn't read any values from the sensor.

I know the sensor is receiving power from the battery because there is a light blinking on the sensor and the Pi recognizes that the sensor is there. Also when I measured the voltage running through the wires from the battery, it says 5.3 V, which is sufficient for the sensor according to the data sheet.

I have the sensor ground and power ports connected to the ground and power wires of a USB cable, which then plugs into the battery.

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

[K-30 CO2 sensor](http://co2meters.com/Documentation/Datasheets/DS30-01%20-%20K30.pdf)

[Battery](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0SC-000Y-00086&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Cell%20Phone%20-%20Power%20Banks-_-0SC-000Y-00086&gclid=CjwKEAiAyO_BBRDOgM-K8MGWpmYSJACePQ9CPZCFMNdbWdGShZcK4v2u6a_ByDBm2EAxeMIcLXXQ_xoChZXw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possible reasons.

1. You didn't connect the ground of the battery/sensor to ground of the RPI.
2. The battery sees too low of a draw and goes to sleep. Common power save feature on newer power banks.
3. The switching supply on the power bank is too noise for the sensor. Try adding a filter cap or two.

Comment: What do you mean by #1? I have the ground of the sensor connected to the ground of the battery. But you're saying one or both should be connected to the RPI?

Comment: @vince yes. Because without the ground of all three connected, they don't have a common reference point.